# How to remove selected image from preview and as well as from url variable before uploading it

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

I have the code for the image preview but after removing it only goes from preview but not from url variable and the removed images url are also being stored in database.

I'm using Spring Boot for controllers.

[how to remove the image while clicking the remove button and also uploaded link from the uploaded files list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk4SO.png)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
          var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            var f = files[i]
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
              var file = e.target;
              $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\"title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
                "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
              $(".remove").click(function() {
                $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
              });

            });
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    input[type="file"] {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .imageThumb {
      max-height: 75px;
      border: 2px solid;
      padding: 1px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .pip {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }
    
    .remove {
      display: block;
      background: #444;
      border: 1px solid black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .remove:hover {
      background: white;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="field" align="left">
    <h3>Upload your images</h3>
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help how to remove the image from preview and also from pojo variable that being saved to database.

Answer (score 0):

Do empty input file field as well

```
 $(".remove").click(function(){
 $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
 $("#files").val(null);
});`
```

Comment: $("#files").val(null);
 this statement removing the total input files url  but i want to remove the specific file url i.e, if i uploaded 5 files i will show the count of 5 , then if i remove one file then specific file url should be removed and it has to display 4 input urls with images